# CSS transition not working when mouse moved off link

Tags: css

im having some troubles with my CSS, i have a button i made and i have given it some CSS to add a color changing effect with webkit transition, the color change works on hover but when mouse is taken off button it wont show effect of it returning to how it was before, heres my css

```
.button-blue{
    border: 1px solid #00B7EF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #00B7EF !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    webkit-property: background-color, color;
    webkit-duration: 0.5s;
}

.button-blue:hover {
    border: 1px solid #00B7EF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #00B7EF;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    webkit-property: background-color, color;
    webkit-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: here it is, its the blue getstarted button is the one im trying to fix :) https://jsfiddle.net/v4o61zg0/

Comment: You don't have any css related to "un-hovering".

Comment: @AMACB thanks for your help but Drinking People has solved it for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have transition properties for your href stated previously so just state it once with your href before and remove the transition properties from your button so your css would look like the following:

Working fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/4hhpg219/)

```
.navigation-bar ul li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 10px;
      -webkit-transition-property: background-color, color;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
      webkit-property: background-color, color;
      webkit-duration: 0.5s;
}
.button-blue{
    border: 1px solid #00B7EF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #00B7EF !important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.button-blue:hover {
    border: 1px solid #00B7EF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #00B7EF;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `webkit-property` and `webkit-duration` **aren't** CSS properties.
   The correct syntax is `transition-property` and
   `transition-duration`.

   > **-webkit-** is only a [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) for CSS features on Google Chrome
   >   and newer versions of Opera.
2. In pseudoclasses as `:hover` state, you only have to declare
   properties that you will change, isn't necessary repeat already
   declared ones. So, border-radius is out (unless you
   want to change it).
3. You have to set the transition in the default state. If you declare
   again on :hover state, you are creating a second instance for the
   transition, that's why you got this animation on your button.
4. You already have declared a transition in `.navigation-bar ul li a` *(And have a transition only for color, not background)*.

   So, now you have a problem with **[specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)**, because targeting a parent class and then directly targeting to an HTML
   element in CSS has more **priority** than targeting only a class
   ([You can check it here](https://specificity.keegan.st/)).
5. If all of your **`a`** element in your `.navigation-bar` will have
   the same transition, you can set it here. *(Not ideal, but it works
   cleaner and will be less changes.)*

   You also need to add a transition for background. This doesn't alter
   the rest of your links, because if you don't set a background in
   hover (or focus) state, it will not change.

   And obviously, you have to remove the transition from
   `.button-blue`, because you will not use it anymore *(It would be
   repetitive).*
6. Try to **modularise** more your CSS *(don't repeat yourself)*. You
   can learn more searching for [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/), [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) or [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/)
   (It's a matter of taste)